# Java - Compare child property on Parent Class Object

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have 2 classes, Foo, and BabyFoo which inherits Foo.  In the Main method, I create an object `Foo f1 = new BabyFoo(3);`.  BabyFoo has a compare method that overrides its parent method, that compares to make sure an object is of the same class, and making sure that the `thing` property is the same value as well.

My question, is in the `compare` method in the `BabyFoo` class, how do I access the `thing` property of the arguement getting passed in, as it is of type `Foo`, as the `Foo` class doesn't have a `thing` property, even though it was created as a `new BabyFoo(3)`.

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public boolean compare(Foo other)
    {
        //compare checks to make sure object is of this same class
        if (getClass() != other.getClass())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
public class BabyFoo extends Foo
{
    protected int thing;

    public void BabyFoo(int thing)
    {
        this.thing = thing;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean compare(Foo other)
    {
        //compares by calling the parent method, and as an
        //additional step, checks if the thing property is the same.
        boolean parent = super.compare(other);
        //--question do-stuff here
        //how do I access other.thing(), as it comes in
        //as a Foo object, which doesn't have a thing property
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to cast the `other` object to be a BabyFoo by writing something like

`((BabyFoo)other).thing`

This is assuming that everything else is how you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the `other` object is of type `BabyFoo`. You can then perform a cast on the object, which would allow you to access the `thing` variable:

```
if (other instanceof BabyFoo)
    BabyFoo bFoo = (BabyFoo) other;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the method gets `Foo` as a variable and not `BabyFoo`, you can't get to it's thing field without casting.

However, casting should be done safely, you need to verify you are comparing to a `BabyFoo` and not `Foo`

```
@Override
public boolean compare(Foo other) {
    return other instanceof BabyFoo &&
       super.compare(other) && 
       this.thing == ((BabyFoo)other).thing;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to downcast `Foo` class to `BabyFoo` class.

```
@Override
public boolean compare(Foo other) {
   if (other instanceof BabyFoo) { // check whether you got the BabyFoo type class
       BabyFoo another = (BabyFoo) other;
       return super.compare(another) && another.thing == this.thing;
   }
   return false;
}
```